# Gui Automation, Install/Uninstall software automatically

Tags: c#, .net, c++, wpf

Can anyone please tell me about any open source software which will install and uninstall software automatically without taking input from user for installation steps.
Any related material will be highly appreciated.

Comment: This may not suit your needs, but some installation packages support unattended installations.  This page looks like a nice source of information on the topic, though I only glanced through it.  http://unattended.sourceforge.net/installers.php

Answer (score 1):

AutoIt. http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/index.shtml

You write scripts as if a user was sitting there doing it themselves. VERY useful.